# Печать данных из textBox

Tags: c#

Как в окно предварительного просмотра для печати вывести информацию из textBox?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю то, что требуется, необходимо работать с сообщениями TextBox. Для RichTextBox есть сообщение [EM_FORMATRANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb788020(v=vs.85).aspx), которое форматирует часть текста для отображения на конечном устройстве, например, принтере. [Пример](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/2502a239-77cb-4072-b37e-1e087ff64841/).